# Java Object String to Json In Post Processing

Tags: java, json, algorithm, parsing, recursion

How can we convert the Java's toString() Object representation into a JSON Object

- For better viewing experience, ie. indentation, collapsibility features

***An Example Java Custom Object (Of Type Person)***

```
Person(firstName=Duke, lastName=Java, age=19, streetAddress=B'`5 CISF "Mujeri Mor" Faridabad, city=JavaTown, state=JA, postalCode=12345, phoneNumbers=[MobilePhoneNumber(mobile=111-111-1111), HomePhoneNumber(home=222-222-2222)], familyMembers=[Person(firstName=Sister, lastName=Young, age=13, streetAddress=Same Address, city=Same, state=Same, postalCode=Same, phoneNumbers=[MobilePhoneNumber(mobile=111-111-1111), HomePhoneNumber(home=222-222-2222)], familyMembers=null, attributes=null, partner=null), Person(firstName=brother, lastName=Old, age=21, streetAddress=Same Address, city=Same, state=Same, postalCode=Same, phoneNumbers=[MobilePhoneNumber(mobile=111-111-1111), HomePhoneNumber(home=222-222-2222)], familyMembers=null, attributes=null, partner=null)], attributes={key_1=value, key 2=123, brother details=Person(firstName=brother, lastName=Old, age=21, streetAddress=Same Address, city=Same, state=Same, postalCode=Same, phoneNumbers=[MobilePhoneNumber(mobile=111-111-1111), HomePhoneNumber(home=222-222-2222)], familyMembers=null, attributes=null, partner=null)}, partner=Person(firstName=Partner, lastName=Same Age, age=21, streetAddress=Same Address, city=Same, state=Same, postalCode=Same, phoneNumbers=[MobilePhoneNumber(mobile=111-111-1111), HomePhoneNumber(home=222-222-2222)], familyMembers=null, attributes=null, partner=null))
```

**Same Above Java Object, Just Indented Manually for better readability**

```
    Person(
        firstName=Duke,
        lastName=Java,
        age=19,
        streetAddress=B'`5 CISF, 'Mujeri Mor', Faridabad,
        city=JavaTown,
        state=JA,
        postalCode=12345,
        phoneNumbers=[
            MobilePhoneNumber(
                mobile=111-111-1111
            ),
            HomePhoneNumber(
                home=222-222-2222
            )
        ],
        familyMembers=[
            Person(
                firstName=Sister,
                lastName=Young,
                age=13,
                streetAddress=Same Address,
                city=Same,
                state=Same,
                postalCode=Same,
                phoneNumbers=[
                    MobilePhoneNumber(
                        mobile=111-111-1111
                    ),
                    HomePhoneNumber(
                        home=222-222-2222
                    )
                ],
                familyMembers=null,
                attributes=null,
                partner=null
            ),
            Person(
                firstName=brother,
                lastName=Old,
                age=21,
                streetAddress=Same Address,
                city=Same,
                state=Same,
                postalCode=Same,
                phoneNumbers=[
                    MobilePhoneNumber(
                        mobile=111-111-1111
                    ),
                    HomePhoneNumber(
                        home=222-222-2222
                    )
                ],
                familyMembers=null,
                attributes=null,
                partner=null
            )
        ],
        attributes={
            key_1=value,
            key 2=123, brother
            details=Person(
                firstName=brother,
                lastName=Old,
                age=21,
                streetAddress=Same Address,
                city=Same,
                state=Same,
                postalCode=Same,
                phoneNumbers=[
                    MobilePhoneNumber(
                        mobile=111-111-1111
                    ),
                    HomePhoneNumber(
                        home=222-222-2222
                    )
                ],
                familyMembers=null,
                attributes=null,
                partner=null
            )
        },
        partner=Person(
            firstName=Partner,
            lastName=Same Age,
            age=21,
            streetAddress=Same Address,
            city=Same,
            state=Same,
            postalCode=Same,
            phoneNumbers=[
                MobilePhoneNumber(
                    mobile=111-111-1111
                ),
                HomePhoneNumber(
                    home=222-222-2222
                )
            ],
            familyMembers=null,
            attributes=null,
            partner=null
        )
    )
```

How can we convert the above Java representation of Person Object into a JSON format?

- I have tried recursion to solve it, but the number of edge cases that I would need to handle, and it does not give me full confidence that the code will parse all the Java Objects correctly

.

Is there a way, I don't have to write a custom parser for this?

And if I have to write a parser, what could be a good approach to take (either by doing some pre-processing or post-processing) that I don't have to handle lots of corner cases due to which the code becomes hard to understand and maintain for longer run

Comment: You can write `toString` however you want, including as JSON. Why parse it? Especially when it's not valid JSON to be parsed?

Answer (score 0):

> convert the Java's toString() Object representation into a JSON Object

You wouldn't.

Just convert the object as is (using Jackson, as an example)

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Person p =...;

String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(p);
```

Comment: Hey assume I don't have the object in the code, I am getting this as a String only
Its like postprocessing, I just get the string representation and now I want to make it JSON for better readability

Comment: So, you have no access to the object itself? What exactly is calling `toString`, and can you change its code?

Comment: No I can't change the code, assume my system as an external system, and lets say in your logs you printing a java object, which is huge and its really hard for you to read it, so you just paste that String in my system and it will provide you a JSON for that which you can now collapse and apply filters on

Comment: please check : [StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286590/objectstring2json-com-tostring-to-json-like-structure)
,
[Reddit Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/t2s7bk/objectstring2jsoncom_tostring_to_json_like/hypndz1/?context=3)

Comment: I think youve gotten valid responses there. Simply dont rely on a language-specific string builder and try to reverse engineer it into a language-agnostic serialization format. Jackson can use reflection against existing objects, so you dont need to modify the external code... Or you could instead inject a slf4j logger that outputs JSON, but your log "messages" themselves will still be strings, and not directly parsable beyond key-value pairs. You can use MDC to extract data you really need to search against

Answer (score 0):

Google's gson has  a pretty similar idea. You can modify the default class to string converter to have a pretty print and specify custom type adapters for fields in the class you would want to process further.

```
    Person duke = new Person("Duke", "Java", 19, " \"name\": \"Bon\", \"streetAddress\": \"355A\" ".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    Gson PrettyGson = new GsonBuilder()
            .registerTypeAdapter(byte[].class,
                    new JsonSerializer() {
                        @Override
                        public JsonElement serialize(Object src, Type typeOfSrc, JsonSerializationContext context) {
                            String byteFieldVal=new String((byte[])src);

                            //......specify additional transformations including more TypeConverters
                            return new JsonPrimitive(finalByteFieldVal);
                        }
                    })
            .setPrettyPrinting().create();

    String donaldJson = PrettyGson.toJson(duke);

    System.out.println(donaldJson);
```

Comment: Hey @douglas, I don't have access to the code, could you please once check the above comments

Comment: Hey @douglas, I don't have access to the code, could you please once check the comments under OneCricketeer's Answer
please check : [StackOverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71286590/objectstring2json-com-tostring-to-json-like-structure)
,
[Reddit Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/javahelp/comments/t2s7bk/objectstring2jsoncom_tostring_to_json_like/hypndz1/?context=3)